# how to calculate border width to scale Image Canvas FabricJS

Tags: javascript, fabricjs, calculator

how to calculate border width to scale Image Canvas FabricJS

The image is smaller but the border size is not smaller.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNF22.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97Tp2.png)

I want the border scale to be the same all the time.
The image is smaller but the border size is not smaller.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>                    
<head>
<title>Custom T-Shirts - Design</title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
      <script src="js/fabric.js" type="text/javascript"></script>     
      <script src="js/customiseControls.min.js"></script>
      <style>
     

        button.accordion-button:focus {
          box-shadow: 0 0 0 0rem transparent!important;
          border-color: transparent!important;
         }

         #ColorpanelDesign {
           float: left;
         }
         .bg-sub {
          background-color: var(--sub)!important;
         }
         .text-sub {
           color: var(--color-sub)!important;
         }
         .accordion-body {
          border: 1px solid var(--sub)!important;
          border-top: 0px;
          width: 100%;
         }
         .designColorBox {
          display: inline-block;
          border: 1px solid #ccc;
          padding: 3px;
          margin-right: 10px;
         }
         .designColor {
           border: 1px solid #ccc;
           width: 30px;
           height: 30px;
         }

         .design-border {
             z-index: 0;
            background-color: grey;position: absolute;
           }
         .canvas-container {
           margin: 0px auto;
         }
         #wrapper {
           position:relative;
          }
          #wrapper > canvas {
            position:absolute;
            left:0;
            top:0;
          }
      </style>
      
</head>                  

<body>
    
    
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-8" style="touch-action: none;padding: 0px;">
          <div id="wrapper">
            <!-- <div class="canvas-container" id="stack"> -->
              <!-- <canvas id="bounded" style="z-index: 1;"></canvas> -->
              <canvas class="lower-canvas" id="mainscreen"  style=" z-index: 0;"></canvas>


              
            <!-- </div> -->
             <div class="design-border  designBox1" style="width: 120px; height: 2px; top: 70px; left: 75px;"></div>
              <div class="design-border designBox2" style="width: 2px;height: 160px;top: 70px;left: 75px;"></div>
              <div class="design-border designBox3" style="width: 2px;height: 160px;top: 70px;left: 195px;"></div>
              <div class="design-border designBox4" style="text-align: center;color: white; width: 120px;height: 20px;top: 210px;left: 75px;font-size: 14px;">Desgin Box</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4" style="padding: 0px;">
          <div class="p-2">
            <div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="accordionFlushExample">
              <div class="accordion-item">
                <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingOne">
                  <button class="accordion-button bg-sub text-sub" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="flush-collapseOne">
                    TYPE
                  </button>
                </h2>
                <div id="flush-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="flush-headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
                  <div class="accordion-body" id="TypepanelDesign">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="accordion-item">
                <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingTwo">
                  <button class="accordion-button bg-sub text-sub" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="flush-collapseTwo">
                    COLOR
                  </button>
                </h2>
                <div id="flush-collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="flush-headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
                  <div class="accordion-body" id="ColorpanelDesign">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    
         
    </div>
  
    <script src="js/fabric.design.js"></script>  
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body> 
    
</html>
```

**fabric.design.js**

```
let dataServer = {
  color: [
    "#fff",
    "#000",
  ]
}
let setDesign = [];
let sizeWidth = document.getElementById("wrapper").offsetWidth
let CvWidth = 540
let CvHeight = 600

let imgWidth = 1
let imgHeight = 1
$(function() {
    
    setDesign["width"] = 200;
    setDesign["height"] = 230;
    setDesign["top"] =  180;
    setDesign["left"] = (sizeWidth / 2) - (setDesign["width"] / 2 + 0); //3 ปรับความเอียง ยิ่งมากยิ่งไปทางซ่าย
  

    let ColorData = dataServer.color
    canvas = new fabric.Canvas('mainscreen', { preserveObjectStacking: true })
    canvas.setHeight(CvHeight)
    canvas.setWidth(CvWidth)
    
    if(screen.width <= CvWidth) {
      canvas.setWidth(screen.width )
      canvas.setHeight(screen.width  * 1.1112)
      // canvas.overlayImage.scaleToWidth(screen.width )
    }

    window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
      if(event.target.outerWidth <= CvWidth) {
        canvas.setWidth(event.target.outerWidth)
        canvas.setHeight(event.target.outerWidth * 1.1112)
        canvas.overlayImage.scaleToWidth(event.target.outerWidth)
      }else{
        canvas.setHeight(CvHeight)
        canvas.setWidth(CvWidth)
        canvas.overlayImage.scaleToWidth(CvWidth)
        
      }

    });

   
    

    for (let i = 0; i < ColorData.length; i++) {
      const element = document.createElement("div")
      element.className = 'designColor'
      element.style["background-color"] = ColorData[i]
      element.setAttribute('color', ColorData[i]);
      element.setAttribute("onclick", "changeColor_Pic('"+ColorData[i]+"')");


      const element_box = document.createElement("div")
      element_box.className = 'designColorBox'
      element_box.appendChild(element)

      document.getElementById("ColorpanelDesign").appendChild(element_box)

      // canvas._objects.map(x => console.log(x))
      
        canvas.setOverlayImage('image/product/front-shirt.png', function() {
          canvas.overlayImage.backgroundColor = dataServer.color[1]
          // console.log(screen.width);
          let width = CvWidth;
          if(screen.width <= width) {
            width = screen.width
          }
            canvas.overlayImage.scaleToWidth(width)
      
           $('.designBox1').css({"width": setDesign["width"]+"px", "height": "2px","top": setDesign["top"]+"px","left": setDesign["left"]+"px"});
           $('.designBox2').css({"width": "2px", "height": setDesign["height"]+"px","top": (setDesign["top"]+2)+"px","left": setDesign["left"]+"px"});
           $('.designBox3').css({"width": "2px", "height": setDesign["height"]+"px","top": (setDesign["top"]+2)+"px","left": (setDesign["left"]+setDesign["width"]-2)+"px"});
           $('.designBox4').css({"width": setDesign["width"]+"px", "height": "20px","top": (setDesign["top"]+setDesign["height"]+2)+"px","left": setDesign["left"]+"px"});
   
            canvas.renderAll()
        })
      // console.log();

      // $('.designBox1').css({"width": setDesign["width"]+"px", "height": "2px","top": setDesign["top"]+"px","left": setDesign["left"]+"px"});
      // $('.designBox2').css({"width": "2px", "height": setDesign["height"]+"px","top": (setDesign["top"]+2)+"px","left": setDesign["left"]+"px"});
      // $('.designBox3').css({"width": "2px", "height": setDesign["height"]+"px","top": (setDesign["top"]+2)+"px","left": (setDesign["left"]+setDesign["width"]-2)+"px"});
      // $('.designBox4').css({"width": setDesign["width"]+"px", "height": "20px","top": (setDesign["top"]+setDesign["height"]+2)+"px","left": setDesign["left"]+"px"});
   }




});
function changeColor_Pic(color,canvasA = canvas) {
  canvasA.setOverlayImage('image/product/front-shirt.png', function() {
    canvasA.overlayImage.backgroundColor = color
    canvasA.renderAll()
  })
  // console.log(color);
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The property you're looking for is called `strokeUniform`. You can use it like this to make a specific image have a constant border size that's independent of scale:

`image.set('strokeUniform', true)`

You can also change the default setting for all images like this:

`fabric.Image.prototype.strokeUniform = true`

Or for all types of objects like this:

`fabric.Object.prototype.strokeUniform = true`

See http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#strokeUniform